# ¿Cómo crear un array con índice dinámico?

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear un `array` con índice dinámico como el ejemplo que muestro:

```
{
   'cod1' : {1,2,3},
   'cod2' : {2,3,4},
   'codx' : {x.......x}
}
```

Donde el índice sea un código de una búsqueda que realizo y cada código contenga **n** elementos

```
{1,2,3, etc...}
```

Pero no sé cómo realizar esto.

Comment: Hola kast, el enunciado de tu problema es muy confuso, por favor trata de redactarlo mejor, además el título no es muy descriptivo que digamos

Comment: arregle el contexto de la pregunta, muchas gracias

Comment: @kast Donde dice `'codx' : {x.......x}`, la _x_ es el número de elementos? es decir `cod20` tendrá _20_ elementos.

Comment: x es un numero al azar y la cantidad de elementos puede ser n elementos

Comment: @kast los valores y la cantidad de estos deben ser al azar ?  o solo la cantidad de elementos?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacerlo con `array` primero debes de agregar el indice con `array.push()`, luego acceder al indice y luego asignarle su valor:

```js
var data = [];
data.push("cod1");
data.push("cod2");
data["cod1"] = [1,2,3]
data["cod2"] = [1,2,3]

console.log(data["cod1"]);
console.log(data["cod2"]);
```

Pero lo mas recomendable es que sea un objecto al estilo diccionario donde puedes agregarle un key de manera dinamica por medio al acceso al indice o dinamicamente:

```js
var data = {};
data["cod1"] = [1,2,3];
data.cod2 = [1,2,3];

console.log(data.cod1);
console.log(data["cod2"])
```

Comment: muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo como *array asociativo* como comentó @Einer o con *JSON* como presento a continuación

```js
var elementos = {
 'cod1': [],
 'cod2': [],
 'cod3': [],
 'cod4': []
};
var cod;
for (cod in elementos){
 var limite = Math.round(Math.random()*10)+1;// Cambiar por la búsqueda
 while (limite--)
  elementos[cod].push(Math.round(Math.random()*50));
}
//Para asegurarnos que se guardó
for (cod in elementos)
 console.log(elementos[cod]);
```

Pero todo depende de para qué lo quieras usar.

Comment: en javascript no existe el "array asociativo", eso es un objeto plano.

Comment: @Emanuel Ve Un arreglo asociativo es una interfaz no un tipo, y sí, el *Objeto plano* en JavaScript sí es un arreglo asociativo.

Comment: @EduenSarceño no dije que fuera un tipo, un objeto plano es una estructura de datos nada maz, sin interfaz. Los array asociativos es una jerga de php, no de javascript.

Answer (score -3):

```
var precios = new Array();

  var items = $(".items")

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    var nombre = $(items[i]).attr("categoria");

    precios[nombre] = $(items[i]).val()

  }
```